# Wait page reload before display text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to reload a page to update the content.

My goal is to reload the page and display text after.

However, the text is display before the end of the reload, so when page is totally reload text disapear.

Is there a solution ?

Thanks

```
...
location.reload();
(result) ? $('#auteur-success').show() : $('#auteur-danger').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page you also reload script, you should end your code on `location.reload();` if you want to show `#auteur-success` after reloading you can use request tags `...?reloaded=true` and check for it after reload

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript link in the body instead of in the head. Just before the body closing tag.

Comment: Can you explain why this solution will solved the problem please?